# highcharts issues in pie chart with gradient fill

Tags: json, highcharts

I am a new to [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) and `json` and I'm using the **pie chart with gradient** fill. I have been facing issues for the past few days with ajaxing in  json data from an external file to populate a pie chart with gradient fill using the library. I have already tried all the suggestions of StackOverflow and Google search though I'm unable to find a particular solution for this.

In my console my json data shows like

```
   [{"name":{"MOZILA":45.0}},{"name":{"IE":26.8}},{"name":{"CHROME":12.8}},{"name":{"OPERA":6.2}},{"name":{"OTHERS":9.2}}]
```

Here is my AJAX call (I omitted unrelated data)

```
    $(function () {

  // Radialize the colors
   Highcharts.getOptions().colors =   Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function(color) {
return {
     radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
    stops: [
        [0, color],
        [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
    ]
    };

    $.getJSON("pie.php", function(json) {  
    // call createChart passing the data to be used 

    options.series[0].data = json;     
    createChart(json);
   });

  });
   }
  function createChart(chartData) {
   // Build the chart
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false
},
title: {
    text: ' Rate of a specific project'
},
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}</b>'
},
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f}',
            style: {
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
            },
            connectorColor: 'silver'
        }
    }
   },
  series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Total without cost',
    data: chartData
   }]
  });
 }
```

Here is my **pie.php**:

```
 $sql="SELECT mozila,ie,chrome,opera,safari,torch FROM webmarketing";
 $resultSql = mysql_query($sql);
  $result = array();
  while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($resultSql)) {
   $result[] = array('name' => 'MOZILA', 'y' => $rows['mozila']);
$result[] = array('name' => 'IE', 'y' => $rows['ie']);
$result[] = array('name' => 'CHROME', 'y' => $rows['chrome']);
$result[] = array('name' => 'OPERA', 'y' => $rows['opera']);
$result[] = array('name' => 'OTHERS', 'y' => $rows['safari']+$rows['torch']);
  }
  print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Data shows on console but graph does not display on the browser.

Comment: @balexandre Now I updated my php and mysql code .Please above code.Still my json data not generate graph.So request to you where is  i am wrong

Comment: @Pawel Fus I kindly request for solution of  this question.

Comment: @Sebastian Bochan Request to you please suggest me the answers.

Comment: What errors do you have in console? What is options variable?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [follow up the documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic/) and see what is the chart expecting, in your example, you are using a Pie Chart, and they have this demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic/

First of all, your output code is not even a valid JSON as the browser names, because they are a string, need to be wrapped by double quotes `"`

as you can see, they are expecting a bit more that what you provide, plus, the data is in the wrong format, the correct that that needs to be output from your PHP script should be:

```
[
    [ "Firefox", 45.0 ],
    [ "IE", 26.8 ],
    [ "Chrome", 12.8 ],
    [ "OPERA", 6.2 ],
    [ "OTHERS", 9.2 ]
]
```

or, by specifying individual values (**JSON Format**)

```
[
    { "name": "Firefox", "y": 45.0 },
    { "name": "IE", "y": 26.8 },
    { "name": "Chrome", "y": 12.8 },
    { "name": "OPERA", "y": 6.2 },
    { "name": "OTHERS", "y": 9.2 }
]
```

or you need to parse it again in javascript...

in your json call, you are doing:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

from their docs, it should be

```
$('#container').highcharts(options);
```

---

From your changes:

I would extract your chart code and add it to a method, like:

```
$(function () {

   // START Radialize the colors
   Highcharts.getOptions().colors = 
     Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function(color) {
       return {
         radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
         stops: [
            [0, color],
            [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
         ]
       };
   });
   // END Radialize the colors

    $.getJSON("pie.php", function(json) {  
        // call createChart passing the data to be used     
        createChart(json);
    });

});

function createChart(chartData) {
  // Build the chart
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
      },
      tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
        }
      },
      series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        data: chartData
      }]
  });
}
```

**But** you need to output the correct JSON format that the chart is expecting (see my answer above so you know what you need to output.

---

you are **outputting this**:

```
[{"name":{"MOZILA":45.0}},{"name":{"IE":26.8}},{"name":{"CHROME":12.8}},{"name":{"OPERA":6.2}},{"name":{"OTHERS":9.2}}]
```

you **need this**:

```
[{ "name":"MOZILA","y":45.0},{"name":"IE","y":26.8},{"name":"CHROME","y":12.8},{"na‌​me":"OPERA","y":6.2},{"name":"OTHERS","y":9.2}]
```

Comment: Thanking you for your response.Ya already add **$('#container').highcharts(options);** . Please Check above code .I updated my code what i am doing.So tell me how can i bond the data together for proper format.

Comment: you still need to update your `php` code as what you are output is not what is expecting, and currently, not a valid JSON. - You are also using 2 times the `document.ready`... I've clean up your script and extracted the chart creation to a method that is called in your `getJson` call... **REMEMBER** that you need to update your `PHP` output!

Comment: Thanks for your response.Please check my updated code.Still now nt generate graph also

Comment: you still have issues with your JSON, you are output: `[[{"MOZILA":45.0},{"IE":26.8},{"CHROME":12.8},{"OPERA":6.2},{"OTHERS":9.2}]]` but in reality should be `[{ "name":"MOZILA","y":45.0},{"name":"IE","y":26.8},{"name":"CHROME","y":12.8},{"name":"OPERA","y":6.2},{"name":"OTHERS","y":9.2}]` - PLUS, you are missing an ending on the block above the `$.getJSON` call - [SEE MY **DEMO** HERE](http://jsbin.com/funun/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Now i updating my code and also json output.But Still now graph not display.So request to you please correct my code with example where i am wrong.please Check my above code

Comment: @user3591823 you can't see that your JSON code is not correct? I know nothing about PHP, but you need to output the correct string in order to work - see the last section of my answer so you see the difference, and until you don't get that right, I can't help you further. Ask another question on how to format your PHP into the proper string, I'm sure it will be answered!

Answer (score 0):

Please try below example, can help you out
I have used JQuery instead of AJAX

**Sql Syntex**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sales` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `month` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=118 ;


INSERT INTO `sales` (`id`, `month`, `amount`) VALUES
(24, 'Apr', '15'),
(25, 'May', '40'),
(26, 'Jun', '26'),
(27, 'Jul', '31'),
(28, 'Aug', '39'),
(29, 'Sep', '25'),
(30, 'Oct', '27'),
(31, 'Nov', ' 32'),
(32, 'Dec', NULL);
```

**index.php**

```
<head>
    <meta name="Gopal Joshi" content="Highchart with Mysql" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Highchart with Mysql Database</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/setup.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>    
</head>

<body>
    <script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <div id="sales" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
```

**setup.js**

It will Create chart and Import Data from another page.

```
var chart;
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var cursan = {
   chart: {
    renderTo: 'sales',
    defaultSeriesType: 'area',
    marginRight: 10,
    marginBottom: 20
   },
   title: {
    text: 'Highchart With Mysql',
   },
   subtitle: {
    text: 'www.spjoshis.blogspot.com',
   },
   xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
   },
   yAxis: {
    title: {
     text: 'Average'
    },
    plotLines: [{
     value: 0,
     width: 1,
     color: '#808080'
    }]
   },
   tooltip: {
       crosshairs: true,
                shared: true
   },
   legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    x: -10,
    y: 30,
    borderWidth: 0
   },

            plotOptions: {

                series: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',  
                    marker: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                }
            },

         series: [{
       color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
    name: 'Test Colomn',
                marker: {
                    fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    lineWidth: 3,
                    lineColor: null // inherit from series
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    rotation: 0,
                    color: '#666666',
                    align: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: -10,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '9px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
                        textShadow: '0 0 0px black'
                    }
                }
   }],
        }

        //Fetch MySql Records
        jQuery.get('js/data.php', null, function(tsv) {
   var lines = [];
   traffic = [];
   try {
    // split the data return into lines and parse them
    tsv = tsv.split(/\n/g);
    jQuery.each(tsv, function(i, line) {
     line = line.split(/\t/);
     date = line[0] ;
                                        amo=parseFloat(line[1].replace(',', ''));
                                        if (isNaN(amo)) {
                                                   amo = null;
                                        }
     traffic.push([
      date,
      amo
     ]);
    });
   } catch (e) {  }
   cursan.series[0].data = traffic;
   chart = new Highcharts.Chart(cursan);
  });
 });
```

**data.php**

```
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db("test", $con);
$result=mysql_query('select * from sales order by id');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['month'] . "\t" . $row['amount']. "\n";
}
```

[Click Here](http://spjoshis.blogspot.in/2013/12/how-to-import-data-from-mysql-table.html) to Read more or Download Example